# Book on Noether theorem and classical field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, field-theory, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

I couldn't follow the derivation of Noether theorem in my QFT book, and have some problems with classical field theory and functional derivatives etc. Is there a book which gives an introduction to these topics? I am only interested in what is needed for QFT.

Comment: Noether theorem is a standard field theory statement whose walkthrough can be found, for example, in the standard book by Goldstein: http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Mechanics-Edition-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023

Comment: W. Greiner’s book “[Field Quantization](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/33406326)” includes very explicit derivations and solved examples about Noether's theorem. It also includes an introduction to the functional derivatives. You might find it pedagogically very useful in this regard. @Loffen

Comment: I read Neuneschwanders book, good book